# Is there a way to conditionally render components without a forceful animation?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

A way to get around react rendering method?

i.e When a new component is conditionally rendered, the components below move further down to accommodate the new entry, but the animation feels forceful, as opposed to something like Transform: translateY etc.

e.g
Home.js

```
return (
<View>

   <View>
      <Text>Render Something </Text>
   </View>

   { showmore ? <Tasks /> : null}


   <TouchableOpacity>
        <Text> Button </Text>
   </TouchableOpacity>


   </View>
)
```

Tasks.js

```
return(
  <View> 
     <Text> render some  more things </Text>
     <Text> render some  more things </Text>
     <Text> render some  more things </Text>
     <Text> render some  more things </Text>
     <Text> render some  more things </Text>
</View> 

)
```

In the above code, on "Showmore is truthy", Touchableopacity is forced down to accommodate the tasks, i understand the need to rerender the layout, as that space was precviously assigned to = null. But i need it a lot more fluid than it is.

I have tried tried hard coded values like:

```
 { showmore ? <Tasks /> : <View style ={{marginVertical: 50}} />}
```

which provides better entry for the Tasks without the "forceful" need to push down components below as the space was already accounted for (but bad practise i am guessing)

-- I also tried onLayout in `<Tasks>` to perhaps transform : translateY the position of components below, from the derived height of height but the output of the  has been rendered before i could even get the value to work within Home.js.

I am lost as to another alternative to work around this. Any suggestions???

Comment: Have you tried wrapping the Task component in an animated view and then animating its height when show more is true?

Comment: Yes. while that happens to work as expected. I think resolving this would be done in the parent screen. Considering the other components below tasks also need to be animated (perhaps slide down) on the entry of the Task component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a straightforward approach using the Layout Animation API that handles all use cases I have tried thus far.

```
import { 
   Animated,
   Easing, 
   withTiming, 
   useSharedValue, 
   useAnimatedStyle 
   }  from 'react-native-reanimated';

  const translateYValue = useSharedValue(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    LayoutAnimation.configureNext(LayoutAnimation.Presets.linear);
    translateYValue.value = withTiming(50, {
      duration: 100,
      easing: Easing.ease,
    });

  }, [showmore])
```

Add all states that you would typically like to cause a change to the layout of the screen in the dependencies of the useEffect.

Answer (score 1):

I spent a bit too long trying to figure out why animating the height caused the components under `Tasks` to behave unexpectedly. The problem was that I was trying to both animate and measure the height of the same view. Once I separated the two everything worked as expected:

Tasks.js

```js
import { View, Text, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import Animated, {
  useSharedValue,
  withTiming,
  useAnimatedStyle,
  interpolate,
} from 'react-native-reanimated';
import useLayout from '../hooks/useLayout';

// used with interpolate to simulate a delay in the animation
const delayedInputRange = [0, 0.5, 1];

export default function ({ showMore }) {
  const [layout, onLayout] = useLayout();
  const anim = useSharedValue(0);
  const animStyle = useAnimatedStyle(() => {
    return {
      height: interpolate(
        anim.value,
        [0, 1],
        // on mobile devices if height is set to 0
        // the View wont  get rendered to screen even
        // with height changes
        [StyleSheet.hairlineWidth, layout.height]
      ),
      // interpolate to simulate delay opacity animation
      opacity: interpolate(anim.value, delayedInputRange, [0, 0, 1]),
      overflow: 'hidden',
      // interpolate to simulate delay marginVertical animation
      marginVertical: interpolate(anim.value, delayedInputRange, [20, 19, 0]),
    };
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    // update sharedValue when toggle changes
    anim.value = withTiming(showMore ? 1 : 0);
  }, [showMore, anim]);
  return (
    <Animated.View style={animStyle}>
      <View onLayout={onLayout}>
        <Text> render some more things </Text>
        <Text> render some more things </Text>
        <Text> render some more things </Text>
        <Text> render some more things </Text>
        <Text> render some more things </Text>
      </View>
    </Animated.View>
  );
}
```

Parent container:

```js
import { Text, View, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import useToggle from './hooks/useToggle';
import Tasks from './components/Tasks';

export default function App() {
  const [showMore, toggleShowMore] = useToggle(false);

  return (
    <View>
      <View>
        <Text>Render Something </Text>
      </View>
      <Tasks showMore={showMore} />
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={toggleShowMore}>
        <Text>Show {showMore ? 'less' : 'more'}</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
}
```

useLayout.js

```js
import { useState, useCallback } from 'react';

export default function useLayout() {
  const [layout, setLayout] = useState({
    width: 0,
    height: 0,
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
  });
  const onLayout = useCallback((e) => setLayout(e.nativeEvent.layout), []);
  return [layout,onLayout]
}
```

useToggle.js

```js
import { useState, useCallback } from 'react';

export default function useToggle(val) {
  const [bool, setBool] = useState(val);
  const toggle = useCallback(() => setBool(prev=>!prev), []);
  return [bool,toggle]
}
```

[demo](https://snack.expo.dev/SypODZF4b)

Comment: I initially tested this using expo web and everything worked fine. After testing this on my phone I realized that the `Task` component needs to have a height greater than 0 in ordered for the animation to function and edited the answer to work on both the web and mobile devices

Comment: I was able to brute it out sometime yesterday. Can you have a look at this. Let me know what you think, as i still have some troubles getting the  Task height. but i am looking to create something similar to that.   Your approach seem alot more resusable though.      https://snack.expo.dev/@curtis202/46549f

Comment: The animation looks nice! I really dislike using the Animation library that react native ships with

Comment: Take a look at the below, you might find it helpful.